# Como deslizar o texto dentro de um input no hover?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

Tenho um input com um width fixo, porém ás vezes o conteúdo ultrapassa o width desse input. Em algum lugar vi uma solução que ao passar o mouse(hover) no input o texto dentro do input deslizava até o final sem mudar a largura do campo.

Como faço isso?

Comment: Tem algum exemplo ? Eu já vi o input aumentar de tamanho conforme vai escrevendo, mas nunca o texto deslizar no hover.
Não entendi muito bem.

Comment: Acho que ele quer um tipo de "marquee". Mas não vi ainda dessa forma que ele descreveu

Answer (score 0):

Se entendi corretamente poderia utilizar um `text-align:right` e um `transition:0.3s ease` para que o texto deslize. Colocar essa configuração no :Hover